# Android Spinner dropdown with value

Tags: android

I have been searching for an example/demo on spinner showing display text tie with value/id.
Eg.
AB  ItemAB
BC  ItemBC
CD  ItemCD
The screen will show list of dropdown of ItemAB, ItemBC... but when I get the value it should give the code AB, BC or CD.
Most of the example I show were simple_spinner_dropdown_item.
I am not sure what words to search for this example, I tried spinner custom layout without success. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out .. 
It may definitely help you what you are trying to achieve.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html